# NodeList Data is not getting removed

Tags: javascript, nodelist, xmlnodelist

I have an array object which has 3 objects. I want to remove all the objects except the first one.

Here is my data which I got from XML:

```
mrArr[0] = <Data>
                <G> "Val" = "5" </G>
           </Data>  
mrArr[1] = <Data>
                <G> "Val" = "6" </G>
           </Data>
mrArr[2] = <Data>
                <G> "Val" = "7" </G>
           </Data>
```

I have created a loop to try and do this but it is only removing one element. What is wrong with my loop?:

```
for(var i = 1; i < myArr.length; i++){
    myArr[i].remove();
}
```

It is removing only one element.

Comment: Is this an array of dom elements?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I have taken array from xml.

Comment: This is what I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. What is shown should work

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question.

Comment: That's not a runnable example

Comment: You said only one is removed and can you make fiddle showing that?

Comment: @charlietfl  I am trying to make that

Comment: Try by changing your forLoop as I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're mutating the array after every iteration, `array.length` keeps decreasing. Hence, in your example, the loop gets executed only once, thereby removing only one element.

Here's a working example of what you're trying to achieve.

```js
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

console.log('Before removal:', nodes);

while (nodes.length > 1) {
  var node = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}

console.log('After removal:', nodes);
```

```html
<div id="div-01">Here is div-01</div>
<div id="div-02">Here is div-02</div>
<div id="div-03">Here is div-03</div>
```

Comment: what's the error? I'm guessing its because `node.remove()` isn't supported in IE; I've updated the answer assuming that's the issue

Comment: Let me try this.

Answer (score 3):

Array does not have a function `remove`. You can use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) like `myArray.splice(1)`;

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(myArray);

myArray.splice(1);
console.log(myArray);
```

If you want to remove not the first item, you need to get the index of the searched item and pass into the `splice` like

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3];
const index = myArray.indexOf(2);
myArray.splice(index, 1);

console.log(myArray);
```

or just use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and pass the predicate

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3];
const filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => item !== 2);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Not getting an option of `splice`

Comment: Array does not have a function called `remove`. `Splice` accepts and `index and count`, means the `index` starting from to remove and `count` - how many items to remove. If `count` is not passed, it removes till to the end. `splice` also affects the current array.

Comment: If you want to remove the first item, there is no difference what data is in it

Comment: The question is with regard to a `Nodelist` and not a regular array. Hence the methods `splice` & `filter` are not applicable here.

Comment: Title is saying `Array`. And it is an `xml` not NodeList

Comment: The title is misleading, but the comment here specifies its an list of dom nodes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363310/array-data-is-not-getting-remove/47363315#comment81679493_47363310

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) works differently than a JavaScript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and what you have there is a `NodeList`. When you delete/remove a node from DOM, it is also removed from any `NodeList` that retains it. Therefore you need to iterate the `.length` of your `NodeList` but you *don't* want your increment expression to actually increment:

```js
dataNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Data");
count = 0; // debug
for (i = 0; i < dataNodes.length; i) {
  console.log('Iteration #',++count,':',dataNodes); // debug
  dataNodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(dataNodes[i]);
}
```

```html
<Data><G>"Val"="5"</G></Data>
<Data><G>"Val"="6"</G></Data>
<Data><G>"Val"="7"</G></Data>
```

The above snippet's `for` loop iterates while `i < dataNodes.length` but *doesn't* increment `i` so `i` for `dataNodes.length` iterations is always `0`. This way it removes index `0` from the `dataNodes` for every iteration. In the console, you can see by removing the `node` from DOM you are *also removing it from the `dataNode` `NodeList`*:

```
Iteration # 1 : (3) [data, data, data]
Iteration # 2 : (2) [data, data]
Iteration # 3 : [data]
```